# How to align content beside sidebar with plain CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My content is hidden behind my sidebar. I want the sidebar
to be fixed on the left.

[image: PROBLEM]

When I use float:left instead of position:fixed I get the result i want, but then my sidebar is not fixed on the left when I am scrolling.

My CSS:

```
.Navbar {
    width: 5%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
    position: fixed;
}
```

Enitre Code:

```js
APP.js

import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Topbar from './components/Topbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Topbar />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
         no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

NAVBAR.js

import React from 'react'
import './Navbar.css';
import { AiFillHome } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { FiSettings } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { FiBarChart } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { CgProfile } from 'react-icons/cg';

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className='Navbar'>
        <ul className='navbar-nav'>
            <li className='nav-item'>
                <a href='lul' class="nav-link">        
                <AiFillHome color='white' size={45} />
                <span className="link-text">Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item'>
                <a href='lul' class="nav-link">        
                <CgProfile color='white' size={45} />
                <span className="link-text">Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item'>
                <a href='lul' class="nav-link">        
                <FiBarChart color='white' size={45} />
                <span className="link-text">Charts</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item nav-item-last'>
                <a href='lul' class="nav-link">        
                <FiSettings color='white' size={45} />
                <span className="link-text">Settings</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

```css
.Navbar {
    width: 5%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-item {
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}

.nav-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 5rem;
}

.link-text {
    display: none;
}

.nav-link svg {
    min-width: 2rem;
    width: 4rem;
}

.Navbar:hover {
    width: 12rem;
}

.Navbar:hover .link-text{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color:White; 
}
```

Comment: Don't use `float` for that. You can set `margin-left: calc(5% + 10px)` to the content so the sidebar won't hide it.

Comment: What's the structure of your site? You should define a content container and give him `margin-left: 5%;`. As soon as you specify a `fixed` position, the element no longer reserves space on the lower layer.

Comment: Have you tried setting `display: block` on the nav-bar? An element that has the display property set to block takes up the available screen width. You can specify the width and height properties for such elements, as you have already done.

Comment: Hey guys, margin-left: 5% doesnt solve my problem exactly, because if i hover on the sidebar, it opens up a bit and then overlaps the content, too.. can i stick margin-left to the sidebar hovering?

Comment: Everything is possible - Can you share your code?

Comment: I postet a bit of my code, i think its all relevant! Thanks for your help

Comment: Please put rendered HTML in your snippet demo. We can't see anything with JSX. This is a CSS question at its core and React isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

so you're using position: fixed; on navbar, so text is behind the navbar (You can learn more on internet about positions and how they work). in your situation i would make div with class page-content and put all things in that div except navbar, and then add this css:

**Example:**

```
.page-content{
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

padding-left will push all content from website except navbar to right. Maybe you will have little problems with responsive later, but its easy to fix with more padding or less.

I'm not 100% sure this is going to work for you, but try it. :D